# Opencv face recognition eigenfaces, unequal size training images

Tags: python, opencv

For a school project I been assigned to create a face recognition app using eigenfaces lib from opencv.
I have been struggling for quite a while now because I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the sizes of the images. I have resized all images to 430x570, yet still I am getting an error saying that the sizes of the images do not match.

*error: (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats) In the Eigenfaces method all input samples (training images) must be of equal size! Expected 17956 pixels, but was 21316 pixels.*

Important to note is that the recognition is done based on pictures taken from a webcam.

I have been having a real hard time adjusting all kinds of sizes within the script and I am sure this is where the error lies.
If anybody could point out what I am doing wrong resizing the images in the code, they would be my hero of the day.

Thanks in advance.

- C.L

**Trainer**

```
import os
import cv2 
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import ctypes
dirAmt = 0
imageFolders = []
osPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
datasetLocation = osPath + '/Photos/dataset'
width_d, height_d = 430, 570  # Declare your own width and height

# Path for face image database
path = 'C:/Users/C/Desktop/hmi/Photos/dataset/all'
# path = 'C:/Users/siemd/Documents/school/jaar 4/hmi/OpenCV-Face-Recognition-master/FacialRecognition/dataset/'
recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('C:/Users/C/Desktop/hmi/Cascades/Haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
# function to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path,imageFolders) for imageFolders in os.listdir(path)]     
    faceSamples=[]
    ids = []

    for imagePath in imagePaths:
        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L') # convert it to grayscale
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img,'uint8')
        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[1].split(".")[0])
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        for (x,y,x,y) in faces:
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y+y,x:x+x])
            #img_numpy[y:y+h,x:x+w], (width_d, height_d

            ids.append(id)

    return faceSamples,ids

print ("\n [INFO] Training faces. It will take a few minutes. Wait ...")
# faces,ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
# recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
faces, ids = getImagesAndLabels(path)
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))
# Save the model into trainer/trainer.yml
recognizer.write('C:/Users/C/Desktop/hmi/trainer/trainer.yml') # recognizer.save() worked on Mac, but not on Pi
# Print the numer of faces trained and end program
print("\n [INFO] {0} faces trained. Exiting Program".format(len(np.unique(ids))))
```

**Recognition **

```
# Import necessary libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os 
import sys

# Get the path of the current working directory
osPath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

# Load the face recognizer model
recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read(osPath + '/trainer/trainer.yml')

# Load the face cascade classifier
cascadePath = osPath + '/Cascades/Haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"C:\Users\C\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

# Set font type
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# Set initial ID and names
id = 0
names = ['none','1', '2:Jurriaan', '3', '4:Bart', '5:Siem', '6', '7','8:Melvin','9:Wessel','10:Yunghui','11:Raoul','12','13:Davy','14:Collin'] 

# Start video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Set video capture resolution
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 430) 
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 570)

# Set minimum face width and height
minW = 0.1*cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
minH = 0.1*cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)

print(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
print("BBBBB")
print(minW)
print("AAAAAAAAAAAAa")
print(minW)
# Start infinite loop for video capture and face recognition
while True:
    # Read video frames
    ret, img =cam.read()
    #print("CAM W/H" + img.w + "/" + img.h)
    
    # Convert frames to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces in the grayscale frame
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale( 
        gray,
        scaleFactor     = 1.1,
        minNeighbors    = 5,
        minSize = (int(minW), int(minH)),
    )
    
    # Draw rectangles around detected faces and recognize them
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        # Draw rectangle around face
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
        # Recognize face
        id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        
        # If recognized with high confidence, display name and confidence level
        if (confidence < 100):
            id = names[id]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        # If unrecognized or recognized with low confidence, display "unknown" and confidence level
        else:
            id = "unknown"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(100 - confidence))
        
        # Display name and confidence level on the frame
        cv2.putText(img, str(id), (x+5,y-5), font, 1, (255,255,255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x+5,y+h-5), font, 1, (255,255,0), 1)  
    
    # Display the video frame with detected faces and recognized names
    cv2.imshow('camera',img) 

    # Exit loop if "ESC" key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff 
    if k == 27:
        break
        
# Release video capture and destroy all windows
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please add more debug log data, e.g. image sizes. Does the error happen during training or recognition? [ask]